# actionButton not triggered in shiny

Tags: r, button, shiny, eventtrigger

I don't understand why my actionButton is not triggered, when I click on it nothing happen. After having tried several things I don't know what to do...

My app:

ui :

```
navbarPage("page", id = "nav",
  tabPanel("tab",

    navbarPage(title = icon("caret-right"), id = "nav",

      tabPanel("Geocodage adresse",
        fluidRow(style = "padding:20px;",
          textInput("geocod_Adress", "Adresse a geocoder:"),
          actionButton("geocod_Geocod", "Calcul des coordonnees", icon("compass")),
          verbatimTextOutput("coordonnees")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Server:

```
function(input, output, session) {
  ntext < - eventReactive(input$geocod_Geocod, {
    return(input$geocod_Adress)
  })

  output$nText < - renderText({
    ntext()
  })
}
```

Comment: Of course in the verbatimTextOutput it's ntext and not coordonnees

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `coordonnees`, it should be `nText`, and not `ntext`, since you want to refer to the `renderText`, and not to the `eventReactive`. Working example:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(style = "padding:20px;",
           textInput("geocod_Adress", "Adresse a geocoder:"),
           actionButton("geocod_Geocod", "Calcul des coordonnees", icon("compass")),
           verbatimTextOutput("nText")
  )
)

server <-function(input, output, session) {

  ntext <- eventReactive(input$geocod_Geocod, {
    return(input$geocod_Adress)
  })

  output$nText <- renderText({
    ntext()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```